# Yarp - single incoming request to multiple services

Tags: ms-yarp

I am reading Yarp docs and different examples, and I am surprised I cannot see example of sending single incoming request to multiple backend services and combine the responses.

So, I want a BFF that would

1. take request to a route `/get-customer-and-orders`
2. send 2 requests: one to `/customer/details/{id}` and one to `/orders/{customerId}`
3. combine responses from 2 backend services and send it back to the client

Is this not possible with Yarp or am I missing something?